# SQLite delete last string - app crashed

Tags: android, sqlite

Can someone help me to point out what is the error? My app crash after I put this.

```
public String getLastString() {

String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

cursor.moveToLast();
LastString = cursor.getString(0);

cursor.close();
db.close();
return LastString;
}


public void deleteLastMessage() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null ,new String[] { getLastString() });
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you add error log and complete code?

Comment: you have not set where a condition in delete query

Comment: `My app crash after I put this` share your crash log with question

Comment: @Nilu Just attached the crash log and complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this, thanks all

```
// Deleting single contact
    public void deleteLastMessage(SubliminalMsg a) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_MSG + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(a.get_message()) });
        db.close();
    }

    public String getLastString() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    cursor.moveToLast();
    LastString = cursor.getString(0);

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return LastString;
}
```

In activity

```
 public void delete(View v) {
    LastMessage = new SubliminalMsg(db.getLastString());
    db.deleteLastMessage(LastMessage);
    displayText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void deleteLastMessage() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"COLNAME = ?",new String[] { getLastString() });
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: you just need to specify a condition, else try `db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);` it will remove every item in that table ,condition will remove item with that condition

Comment: @Anthony it will remove all details from table

Comment: I just want to delete the last entry

Answer (score 0):

Where clause is missing

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"COLUMNNAME = '"+ getLastString()+"'",null});
db.close();
```

Comment: Use the updated answer replace the COLLUMNNAME by your column name .

Comment: Whats the crash report . Post it in question .